# add text to <td> based on <selection> dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have a table I want to populate with data as a user makes a choice using a form.  Eventually it will have cost added to the tco cell.

```
<table style="width:100%; padding:0;margin:0;" id="ch1">
<tbody>
    <tr class=""childname">
        <td class="cn"></td>
        <td class="ca"></td>
        <td class="cs"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cl1">
        <td colspan="2" class="tcl"></td>
        <td class="tco"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cl2">
        <td colspan="2" class="tcl"></td>
        <td class="tco"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I can add the selection to a hidden field `#cl1a` but not the table cell.

```
$("#classA1").change(function () {
var cl1 = '';
$("#classA1 option:selected").each(function () {
        $("#cl1a").val($(this).val());
        $("#resultbox table#ch1 tr.cl1 td.tcl").text($(this).val());
    });
});
```

I know the `#resultbox table@ch1 tr.cl1 td.tcl` is correct because I can change the style using that path.

Comment: Pretty sure he wants to know why the value isn't set as the text of the td.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you wonder why your code is not assigning the value of `option :selected` to the cell `td.tcl`.

Well, first:

- Your HTML is wrong. You need to close the tag `tbody`.
- There also are two quotes in the class `""childname"`, which further spoils the HTML.
- You need your jQuery code to run when the document is ready. I don't know if your full code had it, since you didn't make clear whether it's using `$(document).ready`, what is needed.

So, I created a sample correcting these problems: http://jsbin.com/iruqe5/edit.

Comment: Thanks  Yes I noticed the double quote after submitting the question.  I only showed part of the code and yes the code does look like your sample code. Way cool example BTW

Comment: The issue was I was loading an old version of the js code.  After linking to the proper js file all worked as planned.  I was getting very frustrated and ask as a last resort and after hours of searching for a reason why it did not work.  Thanks again.